Invisibly redirect one domain to another via .htaccess
I'm trying to find a way to redirect my subdomain, let's call it one.example.com, to my other subdomain's subpage two.example.com/one but without the user noticing they are being redirected.
I tried multiple variants in my .htaccess file and searched for quite a while, but all my tries still lead to a visible redirect or a non-working one.
What I found in my google research:
1)
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:one\.)example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(subdir)/?$ https://two.example.com/one [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:one\.)example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://two.example.com/one [NC,L]

-> worked, but did not hide the redirect
2)
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:one\.)example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(subdir)/?$ https://two.example.com/one [P]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:one\.)example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://two.example.com/one [P]

-> did not work
3)
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^one.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://two.example.com/one [P]
</IfModule>

-> also didn't work
Does someone have an idea for me? I am not really familiar with .htaccess specifics so any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Variant 2 should work, if you have loaded and enabled the proxy and the proxy_http module ... If that is the case then you should consult your http server's error log file to see what is wrong.
